# Swift - How to sort and array by optional property

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

Say I have a Cat class with this property:

```
var order: Int?
```

I have an array of these classes that I need to order by this property:

```
let sortedCats = cats.sorted(by: { $0.order > $1.order })
```

I get this error:

```
"Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' operands"
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: It depends on how you want to treat the orderless cats (those whose order == nil). Should an orderless cat compare less than or greater than any ordered cat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a default value of `.min` which is the smallest number you can have on an `Int`

`let sortedCats = cats.sorted(by: { $0.order ?? .min > $1.order ?? .min })`